# FullCalendar event directing to wrong url

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, url, fullcalendar

So I have set up FullCalendar to my site.
I used [this tutorial](http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2013/06/jquery-fullcalendar-integration-with.html).

Everything works fine except the urls I add to events on my calendar. So when I've added a URL to an event it should direct me to that url when I press on the event.

For example, when I add `www.eventurl.com` to my event it doesn't direct me to it, but it directs me to `www.mysiteurl.com/www.eventurl.com`. When I inspect that element with my browser I can see that there are `href="www.eventurl.com"`. So it looks like it should use that URL, but when I press on the event it goes to `www.mysiteurl.com/www.eventurl.com`.

I would be really thankful if someone know how to fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: here URL should not include domain/port number and all..
URL is a relative path to your root web folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

When JavaScript promt() asks me what url I would like to attach to my event I didn't add 'http://' in front of it. So when I did that, it worked!